# i am have an issue with post request in the chatbot ap using watson assistant

Tags: post, httprequest, chatbot

while sending a post request on postman after session id is generated, it goes to catch block, and it shows error

```
Error: Missing required parameters: sessionId
    at Object.getMissingParams (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\helper.js:116:11)  
    at AssistantV2.message (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\ibm-watson\assistant\v2.js:217:50)
    at E:\Projects\ChatBot App\routes\api\watson.js:44:41
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\Projects\ChatBot App\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

the code is:

```
router.post('/message', async (req, res) => {
    payload = {
        assistantId: process.env.WA_ASSISTANT_ID,
        sessionId: req.headers.session_id,
        input: {
            message_type: "text",
            text: req.body.input,
        },
    };

    try {
        const message = await assistant.message(payload);
        res.json(message["result"]);

    } catch (err) {
        res.send("There was an error processing your request.");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

[image: Postman post error]

Comment: It says "Error: Missing required parameters: sessionId". Did you send it? The code is code, but you used postman and did not show how you used it.

Comment: oh sorry, yes i did, i put the session_id and the generated id in key value pairs and then gave input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot of Postman shows that you added session_id as URL parameters. That would be for a GET request. You need to transfer the assistantId and session_id as payload of the POST request, i.e., as data in the request body. Then it should work.

This is not related to IBM Watson Assistant, but how [http requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_messages) work.

Comment: I did not add session_id as URL parameters , In key I added session id and In value the generated id and when i sent the request it gets added on  its own

Comment: That is the same. They need to be part of the body.